# Segment Range Values in a Gauge

Tags: einstein-analytics

I'm trying to dynamically set the segment range values of a gauge in Analytics.  However the section in Range Values only appears to have a Min and a Max (and setting them in the JSON directly seems to be entirely ignored).  I played with conditional formatting, but there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically choose the values for the colors there.  Did these options get moved somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being, at least in Summer 18, that you have to edit the JSON itself and specify conditional formatting as either null or false.  Details can be found [here](http://www.salesforceblogger.com/2018/08/09/how-to-make-the-gauge-chart-dynamic-again/).